# Return Count on SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

There's a table that has a column populated with a value that is in hexadecimal. I've been able to convert it, but now I'm looking at harvest one parameter out of it.

Here's my query that I've been using to convert hex to varchar

```
SELECT SD.ScriptID, MS.EnterpriseName AS ScriptName, S.Version, CAST(CAST(SD.ScriptData AS varbinary(MAX)) AS varchar(MAX)) AS Converted_SD
FROM Script_Data (nolock) SD
JOIN Script (nolock) S ON (S.ScriptID = SD.ScriptID)
JOIN Master_Script (nolock) MS ON (MS.MasterScriptID = S.MasterScriptID)
AND (S.Version = MS.CurrentVersion OR (MS.CurrentVersion=-1 AND MS.NextAvailableVersion=S.Version+1))
AND MS.EnterpriseName = 'Test'
```

I've attached screen shot of what the query returns:

[image: Query Results]

I cut off the the whole value of Converted_SD because it just goes on forever. What I'm most interested in is **{20 ScriptStart**

I just want the '**20**' returned. I've been trying to parse this out to no avail. Expert help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `charindex()` :

```
select substring(col, charindex('{20', col)+1, 2)
```

However, it will return other numbers too if `{20` not found. So, you can do to return null :

```
select right(substring(col, nullif(charindex('{20', col), 0), 3), 2)
```

Note : It will easier to accommodate the above with existing query.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I left out an important note. That '20' is not always 20... it can be any number, but what IS always consistent is ScriptStart